# Book Translator

Tags: translation

I sometimes need to read (often old) books of other language in mathematics, physics and philosophy. I need to translate the entire books to English. Which is the optimal software for me?

Edit: I want to use it in Windows 8. I am ready to pay for all range of cost, if it is useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

As a translation scholar, I feel puzzled by your wish for a piece of software to read books about subjects as deep as the ones you've mentioned in other languages.

Please refer to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAgp7nXdkLU